# hierarchical data types

Tags: haskell

I would like to define data types hierarchically, such as:

```
data Cat = BigCat | SmallCat
data Animal = Cat | Dog
```

And then write a function that will take Animals as arguments, and write it with pattern matching like this:

```
bigger::Animal -> Animal -> Bool
bigger SmallCat BigCat = False
bigger BigCat SmallCat = True
bigger Dog Cat = True
bigger Cat Dog = False
```

The compiler complains. It doesn't want to match the type `Animal` explicitely written in the function signature against the type `Cat` in the first and second lines of pattern matching. Why won't haskell admit that a big cat or small cat *is* an animal?

Comment: "Why won't haskell admit that a big cat or small cat is an animal?" - Because it isn't. `BigCat :: Cat` and `SmallCat :: Cat`, but `Cat :: Animal`. The *constructor* `Cat` has no relation to the *type* `Cat`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You mix up *types* with their *constructors*. A type is something of which you can create variables. A type constructor is what you use to create such data. In you code, `data Animal = Cat | Dog` declares a *type* `Animal` with the two *constructors* `Cat` and `Dog`. In the other line, you define a datatype `Cat`. This is no problem since types and constructors don't share the same namespace.

If you want to have an object of type `Cat` embedded in your `Animal` (if the constructor `Cat` is used), you can add a field to the constructor:

```
data Animal = Cat Cat | Dog
```

This means: *"`Animal` is a type that has two constructors, `Cat` and `Dog`. `Cat` has a field of type `Cat` and `Dog` has none."* If you want to create objects with the constructor `Cat`, you have to pass an object of type `Cat` to it:

```
myCat = Cat BigCat
```

If you want to match on an `Animal`, you have to list all fields of the matched constructor. Compare a corrected version of your code:

```
data Cat = BigCat | SmallCat
data Animal = Cat Cat | Dog

bigger :: Animal -> Animal -> Bool
bigger (Cat SmallCat) (Cat BigCat)   = False
bigger (Cat BigCat)   (Cat SmallCat) = True
bigger Dog            (Cat _)        = True
bigger (Cat _)         Dog           = False
```

The `_` denotes a *don't care* - regardless of the object passed, this will always match.

Comment: +1 for an explanation of the distinction between types and constructors appropriate for a beginner.

Answer (score 12):

The immediate error here is that `Animal` is defining two data constructors, which have nothing to do with `Cat`: The expression `Cat` is of type `Animal`, while the expression `BigCat` is of type `Cat`.

To create nested data types in simple fashion, you'd need to make the `Cat` type an argument to the relevant constructor:

```
data Cat = BigCat | SmallCat
data Animal = Cat Cat | Dog
```

You can then do something like this:

```
bigger (Cat SmallCat) (Cat BigCat) = False
bigger (Cat BigCat) (Cat SmallCat) = True
bigger Dog (Cat _) = True
bigger (Cat _) Dog = False
```

This becomes exceeding clumsy if extended beyond a trivial example, however, the redundancy in the `Cat` type is painful, and the two different uses of the identifier `Cat` is needlessly confusing. A slight improvement is to avoid conflating size with species, and instead do something like this:

```
data Size = Big | Small
data Species = Cat | Dog
data Animal = Animal Species Size
```

An advantage here is that you can more easily extend either types without having to add as much boilerplate nonsense as would otherwise be required.

However, both of these are very silly as anything other than toy examples and in actual use there's very likely to be a much better approach that would be preferable. If the types really are simple enumerations more meaningful than cats and dogs, then `deriving` `Ord`, `Enum`, &c. is preferable to special-purpose stuff. If the intent is a more open-ended way of modelling entities with various properties, it's worth thinking about other designs more tailored to the actual problem.